# Remove some words replace some other words from a txt file

Tags: python, string, file-io, replace

I have a txt file (myText.txt) containing many lines of text.

I would like to know :

- How to create a list of word that needs to be deleted **(I want to set up the words myself)**
- How to create a list of word that needs to be replaced

For instance if myText.txt is:

```
    The ancient Romans influenced countries and civilizations in the following centuries.  
Their language, Latin, became the basis for many other European languages. They stayed in Roma for 3 month.
```

- I would like to remove "the" "and" "in" I would like to replace
  "ancient" by "old"
- I would like to replace "month" and "centuries"
  by "years"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use a regex:

```
import re

st='''\
The ancient Romans influenced countries and civilizations in the following centuries.  
Their language, Latin, became the basis for many other European languages. They stayed in Roma for 3 month.'''

deletions=('and','in','the')
repl={"ancient": "old", "month":"years", "centuries":"years"}

tgt='|'.join(r'\b{}\b'.format(e) for e in deletions)
st=re.sub(tgt,'',st)
for word in repl:
    tgt=r'\b{}\b'.format(word)
    st=re.sub(tgt,repl[word],st)


print st
```

Comment: hello is very nice working . Just a question sometimes i have in my text the "+" and the "-" sign. However it seems that Python not accept deletions=('and','in','the','+','-')  Is there a special way to enter those caracters? Thanks you

Comment: There are certain characters that have meaning to a regex like `+` and `-` My suggestion is spend some time with a regex tutorial site and learn those characters. [Regex101](http://www.regex101.com) is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. You use a list to store the objects you want to delete, and then loop through the list and remove every element in the list from the contents string. Then, you use a dictionary to store the words you have now and the words you want to replace them with. You also loop over those and replace the current words with the replace ones.

```
def replace():
    contents = ""
    deleteWords = ["the ", "and ", "in "]
    replaceWords = {"ancient": "old", "month":"years", "centuries":"years"}

    with open("meText.txt") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    for word in deleteWords:
    contents = contents.replace(word,"")

    for key, value in replaceWords.iteritems():
    contents = contents.replace(key, value)
    return contents
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just get an error message "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'" I just the latest version of Python. Is it normal ? Thank you.

Comment: If you're using python 3, then say replaceWords.items()

Answer (score 2):

Use a list for deletion and dictionary for replacement. It should look something like this:

```
 def processTextFile(filename_in, filename_out, delWords, repWords):


    with open(filename_in, "r") as sourcefile:
        for line in sourcefile:
            for item in delWords:
                line = line.replace(item, "")
            for key,value in repWords.items():
                line = line.replace(key,value)

            with open(filename_out, "a") as outfile:
                outfile.write(line)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    delWords = []
    repWords = {}

    delWords.extend(["the ", "and ", "in "])
    repWords["ancient"] = "old"
    repWords["month"] = "years"
    repWords["centuries"] = "years"

    processTextFile("myText.txt", "myOutText.txt", delWords, repWords)
```

Just a note, this is written for Python 3.3.2 which is why I am using items(). Use iteritems() if using Python 2.x as I think it is more efficient especially for large text files.

Comment: thank you for this code. Wow there is many way to achieve my aim :)